# Guardar y Cargar struct C

Tags: c

Vuelvo con otra pregunta porque llevo ya todo el día en ello, quiero almacenar los datos del `struct` en un fichero, pero me da error. Antes de poner el código os explico que tengo la variable `contador`, que es donde almaceno cada vez que añado un `item`.

Al guardar el `struct` lo guardo en `TXT` para poder visualizar los datos sin codificar, pero salen valores aleatorios y símbolos. Por otro lado, a la hora de cargar no me carga nada, detecta que hay algún dato, pero no me detecta los datos como tal ¿por qué?  Cuando voy a borrar un ejemplar o modificar no me indica que este vacía la `BDD`.

**Guardar:**

```
 void Guardar(tRegLista *reg)
{
    FILE *pfichero;
    int i;
    pfichero=fopen("BIBLIOTECA.DAT","w+b");
    if(pfichero!=NULL){
        fwrite(reg->contador,sizeof(reg->contador),1,pfichero);
        for(i=0;i<reg->contador;i++){
            fwrite(&reg[i],sizeof(reg[i]),1,pfichero);
        }
    }
    fclose(pfichero);
}
```

**Cargar:**

```
void Cargar(tRegLista *reg)
{
    FILE *pfichero;
    pfichero=fopen("BIBLIOTECA.DAT","rb");
    if(pfichero!=NULL){
        fread(&reg->contador,sizeof(reg->contador),1,pfichero);
        while(!feof(pfichero)){
            fread(&reg[reg->contador],sizeof(reg[reg->contador]),1,pfichero);
            reg->contador++;
        }
        reg->contador--;
    }
    fclose(pfichero);
}
```

**Struct:**

```
typedef struct
{
    char nomEditorial[TAM];
    int numPagina;

} tRegLibros;

typedef struct
{
    char nomRevista[TAM];
    int numRevista;
    int paginaInicio;

} tRegArticulos;

typedef struct
{
    char titulo[50];
    char autor[TAM];
    char idEjemplar[5];
    int anioPubli;
    int prestado;
    char fecha[20];
    char dniSocio[9];
    char clave[4];

    union
        uTipo
    {
        tRegArticulos articulo;
        tRegLibros libro;
    } uTipo;
} tRegEjemplares;

typedef struct
{
    tRegEjemplares ejemplar[maxEJEMPLARES];
    int contador;
    int contadorLibros;
    int contadorArticulo;
} tRegLista;
```

**Main:**

```
tRegLista reg;
```

Comment: Que error te marca?

Comment: Pues el compilador ninguno pero no me guarda los datos dentro del archivo txt esta vacio o muchas veces me salen simbolos raros cuando cambio el reg-> contador por reg->ejemplar pero son datos aleatorios sin sentido

Comment: Pues mira es muy difícil para mí (con lo mostrado) saber que esta mal con tu código. Pero si yo fuera tu  colocaría esta linea después de que tomó los datos, dentro del ciclo while `printf("registro [ %d ] almacena %d \n" , reg->contador, reg[reg->contador] ); ` de esa forma por lo mennos se si los esta leyendo bien.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder a ver leer los lee y los mete en el array porque tengo otras funciones como baja y modificación y van perfectas! Lo que no se es que ponerte para que me puedas ayudar mira te comento algo más el struct se llama treglista lista y en el main me he declarado el treglista reg que es el que utilizo para pasarlo a los sub programas el contador lo inicializo dentro de main y no se que dato más darte :/

Comment: He añadido info del struct arriba a ver si os ayuda

Comment: Que errores te muestra? El problema esta a la hora de guardar los datos o a la hora de guardarlos como archivo?

Comment: A la hora de guardar el archivo yo abro el txt y no salen los datos salen simbolos raros, y cuando lo "cargo" no se carga osea no hay datos porque doy la opcion de borrar ejemplares y me dice no hay ejemplares en la base

Comment: Deberías añadir esto a tu pregunta, para que eliminen la espera. Por otro lado el problema entonces estará en la función de carga de datos, por lo que al estar vacía la información, te muestra símbolos aleatorios.

Comment: Yo creo que esta en introducir porque ya te digo lo guardo sin codificar en TXT no en DAT y deberia de poder ver los datos introducidos y no es asi. Por otro lado probablemente la de cargar tambien este mal, por eso digo a ver si alguien puede arrojar un poco de luz al asunto, a lo de eliminar la espera a que te refieres?

Comment: La pregunta esta en espera por lo que nadie puede contestar hasta que se considere que tu pregunta es clara y has adjuntado suficiente información para entenderla.

Comment: Puede ser que el problema este en el 3 parámetro que pasas en la función fread, en este debes poner el numero de datos que deseas leer multiplicado, ademas, por el numero de bytes de cada dato, y este no puede exceder el tamaño del array del primer parametro. Si no me equivoco tu usas un entero en vez de un array, el llamado contador.

Comment: contador es una variable del array que almacena con int el numero de ejemplares nada mas, y si podeis poner codigo para verlo mas claro, ya sabes que asi de palabra es complicado ver las cosas jaja :)

Comment: @Peter Creo que confundes el uso de fread, cuando acepten la pregunta te intentare contestar de forma mas clara. Te recomiendo que leas esta información para solucionar tus dudas http://www.chuidiang.org/clinux/ficheros/fichero-binario.php

Comment: @ElPatrón Perfecto muchas gracias! voy a mirarme lo que me pasaste!

Comment: Mmmm...lo de los caracteres raros es porque no estas grabando en forma de texto...estas grabando en forma binaria. Probá cambiando el "w+b" por "w" en el fopen de guardar y cambia el "rb" por "r" en el fopen de cargar.

Comment: Recuerdo que había un tema con los `Struct`, el compilador puede elegir optimizarlos y hacer que cada "campo" tenga un tamaño múltiplo del campo mayor, esto funciona cuando los tratamos en memoria, pero cuando hay que salvarlos a un archivo lo que ocurre es que algunos campos pueden no tener el tamaño esperado al leer. Al menos en el Gcc había una forma de evitar esta optimización agregando: `__attribute__ ((packed))` Cualquier cosa, [acá](https://pmoracho.github.io/blog/2016/10/11/Alineado-de-memoria-en-C/) está mejor explicado.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho eso te puede suceder si usas diferentes versiones del programa... dentro del mismo programa un `struct` va a ocupar exactamente lo mismo porque el compilador o aplica la optimización a todo o no la aplica a nada

Comment: @EmilianoTorres si escribes en binario y lees en binario no debería haber ningún problema. Otra cosa es que estuvieses almacenando direcciones de memoria en el fichero... pero no parece ser el caso

Comment: No recuerdo bien si es correcto pero para usar fwrite y fread con estructuras en vez de guardar los elementos uno a uno le pasas a direccion de la estructura con &miestructura y el tamaño de esta con sizeof y ella se guarda de una sola vez, esto se llama serialización en otros lenguajes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado el error, logicamente era un un paso de parametros de un subprograma a otro tenia que pasar las variables con

> &*

y las pasaba solo con &. Muchas gracias a los demas por vuestras respuestas! Saludos :)

Answer (score 1):

```
void Cargar(tRegLista *reg)
{
    FILE *pfichero;
    pfichero=fopen("BIBLIOTECA.DAT","rb");
    if(pfichero!=NULL){
        fread(&reg->contador,sizeof(reg->contador),1,pfichero); // (1)
        while(!feof(pfichero)){
            fread(&reg[reg->contador],sizeof(reg[reg->contador]),1,pfichero); // (3)
            reg->contador++; // (2)
        }
        reg->contador--;
    }
    fclose(pfichero);
}
```

Si en `(1)` ya has leído el número de elementos... ¿Por qué actualizas nuevamente la variable en `(2)`? Por otro lado fíjate que si inicializas `reg->contador` con el número de registros cuando intentas recuperar el primer registro lo vas a almacenar en `reg->ejemplar[reg->contador]` (el comentario etiquetado como `(3)` debidamente corregido).

¿Solución?

Usar una variable local para almacenar el número de registros:

```
void Cargar(tRegLista *reg)
{
    FILE *pfichero;
    pfichero=fopen("BIBLIOTECA.DAT","rb");
    if(pfichero!=NULL){
        int numRegistros;
        fread(&numRegistros,sizeof(numRegistros),1,pfichero);
        reg->contador = 0; // Importante!!!
        while(!feof(pfichero)){
            fread(&reg->ejemplar[reg->contador],sizeof(tRegEjemplares),1,pfichero);
            reg->contador++;
        }

        reg->contador--; // <<--- AQUI

        if( reg->contador != numRegistros )
        {
          // Por si quieres mostrar un error por haber una inconsistencia
        }
        fclose(pfichero);
    }
}
```

¿Qué sentido tiene la línea que te destaco con el comentario? Lo que sucede es que `feof` solo se va a activar **después** de realizar una lectura errónea, luego tal y como tienes programado el bucle la última lectura va a ser incorrecta... después incrementas el contador y para compensar ese error te toca decrementarlo... ¿Qué sucede si en el fichero no hay registros? Que el contador acabará valiendo `-1`...

¿Solución a este nuevo problema? Hacer los chequeos cuando realmente toca

```
void Cargar(tRegLista *reg)
{
    FILE *pfichero;
    pfichero=fopen("BIBLIOTECA.DAT","rb");
    if(pfichero!=NULL){
        int numRegistros;
        fread(&numRegistros,sizeof(numRegistros),1,pfichero);
        reg->contador = 0;
        if(!feof(pfichero)){ // Por si acaso el fichero está vacío
          fread(&reg->ejemplar[reg->contador],sizeof(tRegEjemplares),1,pfichero);
          while(!feof(pfichero)) {
            reg->contador++;
            fread(&reg->ejemplar[reg->contador],sizeof(tRegEjemplares),1,pfichero);
        }

        if( reg->contador != numRegistros )
        {
          // Por si quieres mostrar un error por haber una inconsistencia
        }
        fclose(pfichero);
    }
}
```

Queda un poco más feo en el sentido de que tienes que duplicar la línea que lee del fichero pero al menos así evitas valores incorrectos. Otra posibilidad:

```
void Cargar(tRegLista *reg)
{
    FILE *pfichero;
    pfichero=fopen("BIBLIOTECA.DAT","rb");
    if(pfichero!=NULL){
        int numRegistros;
        fread(&numRegistros,sizeof(numRegistros),1,pfichero);
        reg->contador = 0;
        if(!feof(pfichero)){ // Por si acaso el fichero está vacío
          while(1) {
            fread(&reg->ejemplar[reg->contador],sizeof(tRegEjemplares),1,pfichero);
            if(feof(pfichero)) break;
            reg->contador++;
          }
        }

        if( reg->contador != numRegistros )
        {
          // Por si quieres mostrar un error por haber una inconsistencia
        }
        fclose(pfichero);
    }
}
```

Nota también que he movido la instrucción `fclose`. No tiene demasiado sentido intentar cerrar un fichero que no has podido abrir. Tal y como lo tenías no iba a fallar, pero así tiene un uso más acertado.

Comment: Vale he modificado el de cargar como me has indicado, pero creo que el problema esta al guardar el struct no me lo guarda yo creo osea si crea el archivo BIBLIOTECA.DAT. Pero cuando ejecuto y le doy a listar no hay nada. En cambio si añado y después listo si que esta lo que añadí pero claro es porque no hago las funciones de guardado y carga.

Comment: @Peter Nota que te corregí el acceso a los elementos (no es `reg[i]` sino `reg->ejemplar[i]`) y ese mismo error lo tienes también en la escritura. También deberías comprobar que el valor de `reg->contador` es el que esperas.